# \copy statement in PostgreSQL using R

Tags: r, postgresql

I want to execute the following statement on postgresql sending it from R:

```
tname = 'foo'
con = some_connection_to_postgresql
q = paste("\\COPY", tname, "FROM 'foo.csv';")
dbGetQuery(con, q)
```

However, when I execute it, I get the following error:

```
Error: <SQL> '\COPY foo FROM 'foo.csv''
    nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42601: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\";
Error while executing the query
```

However, the same script written from the terminal works perfectly fine.

Comment: have you tried just with `copy` without ` \\`?

Comment: R is sending a *string*. The way to escape `\ ` itself is to type it twice. Why do you assume that *string* contains 2 backslashes? Did you check its contents? If it contained two backslashes you'd see four of them

Comment: `nchar("\\")` returns 1. `nchar("\\COPY")` returns 5. There are no duplicate backslashes in those strings even though the console shows two of them. It's a *single* backslash escaped

Comment: Why do you assume there are two backslashes? Do you get an error from PostgreSQL? What error is it?

Comment: Youre right. I have reformulated the question because it is not the backslash. However, what is it then?

Comment: if you're not using `psql`, just use `copy` instead of `\copy`

Comment: @Jim Jones: Unfortunately that does not work because I have not the right permission to access the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\copy` is not a postgresql statement. the `psql` CLI converts `\copy`...`from filename` into `copy` ... `from stdin;` and then pipes the file's contents over the postgres connection.

you'll have to do the same if you want to use copy.

Comment: do you know it the latter is possible from within R?

Comment: `dbWriteTable()`  seems not fully implemented yet.  maybe in another 5 years?